# Where to implement colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm absolutely newbie in Unity but have some experience in development. Now I'm studying Unity and I have faced with colliders, So my question who should take care of collisions. For instance, In my simple game exists one player and couple different game objects like some power-ups. Currently, I have a script for these power-ups with the implemented logic of collision. But I thought maybe my Player object should implement this logic and check the object collided with him. I mean in real life if a person interacts with a pen, the pen now nothing about a person and interactions, all logic in the human head. I hope I was clear :)

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion.  Ask 3 developers their opinion on where this code should live and you're going to get 3 different answers.  Could be a script on the object, could be a script on the player, could be a collision manager script.  It really just depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the object that cares about the collision should detect them. So a player might detect if it hits spikes, and act accordingly (get damaged). But those spikes might also want to detect the player and also act accordingly (get destroyed).

Try to separate logic this way and your program will be much easier to extend. For example, what if bad guys walk around, and should get damaged, but not destroy the spikes? The spike can check if what hit it was an object implementing "SpikeDestroyer" interface (which the player also implements). And the bad guys can just ignore spikes completely.